# Is limit process countable?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Is the general limit process $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x$$ countable for $n$?What I mean is  the take-values of $n$.

Comment: Do you intend to ask if $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ is always countable?

Comment: What is a 'take-value' of $n$?

Comment: Yes,it seems equivalently,but is it true?$\{x_n:n\in N\}$ is clearly countalbe.

Answer (score 1):

As already hinted in the commentsL if you meant to ask whether the sequence $\,\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ is countable the answer, almost trivially, is yes (unless for you "countable" means *also* infinite, since the sequence can be, for example, constant), and this is due to the fact that we're actually *counting* the elements in that set by means of their *natural* index.

If you meant something else then you should define it. I, for one, don't know what "countable process" can mean (other than the above)